# How to append a line to /etc/fstab via ssh

Tags: command-line, permissions, mount, ssh, fstab

I have a hdd automount program written.

The software uses ssh in order to issue requests against the target machine.
The Idea is that a newly installed hdd is automatically added to fstab.

I have gotten everything working to the point where the fstab line enty is ready to be appended to the file.

I am trying to append like this in my software:

```
command.RunCommandSudo($"echo \"{mountstring}\" >> /etc/fstab");
```

resulting in an ssh query of the following format:

```
sudo echo "UUID=X /mnt/test ext4 defaults 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
```

=> Permission denied

how would be an apropriate way? I doubt the apropriate way for an automated software would be to go through a text editor such as nano?

Comment: I think that command-line indirection (>>) can't be interpreted as being bound to the echo, so to speak.  My guess is it ends up taking output from the sudo instead.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use the `tee` command.

```
NAME
       tee - read from standard input and write to standard output and files

SYNOPSIS
       tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.

       -a, --append
              append to the given FILEs, do not overwrite
```

So, for your command you could do it this way:

```
echo "UUID=X /mnt/test ext4 defaults 0 1" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
sudo su -c "echo 'UUID=X /mnt/test ext4 defaults 0 1' >> /etc/fstab"
```

Mind that a script like this should be used by user root and not your admin so that would negate the use of sudo.

I am more into doing it like this:

```
grep -q '/mnt/test' /etc/fstab || 
printf 'UUID=X /mnt/test ext4 defaults 0 1\n' >> /etc/fstab
```

using user root to do this.